# GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity method not found

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I have installed **aws-sdk(2.2.34) npm module** in my app and trying to get **developer identity** using one of the CognitoIdentity method **getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity()**.

```
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
  var params = {
     IdentityPoolId: 'your_cognito_identity_pool_id',
     Logins: {
        "your_developer_authenticated_identity_name": req.body.user_id
     }
  };
  cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); res.json({failure: 'Connection failure'}); }
     else {
        console.log(data); 
        res.json(data); 
     }
  });
```

But it is saying getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity() method not found. Please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error you're seeing -- running the code sample locally works fine with the version you specify. Is there any additional context you could provide?

Comment: Oops, that's my bad. My IDE showing method not found but it is working fine.